# How to create a custom gradle in Unity 2021?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a WebView in Unty for Andorid, it already works the problem I have is that when I enter Google Maps the GPS function is not activated, already in the Andorid library I create the permission access in the WebView but I get it in the Unity Logcat this mistake

```
 Failed resolution of: Landroidx/core/content/ContextCompat
```

Now I see in other forums that I have to increase this in the unity gradle

```
Implemts  'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
```

but I don't know how to make the custom gradle or how to increase that part

Answer (score 0):

The solution: Unity already has a default class to ask for localization permissions

```
using UnityEngine.Android;

  if (!Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission(Permission.CoarseLocation) && 
      !Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission(Permission.FineLocation))
   {
       Permission.RequestUserPermission(Permission.CoarseLocation);
       Permission.RequestUserPermission(Permission.FineLocation);
   }
```